# Quicken google apps script so I can return success response within Shopify 5 second limit

Tags: google-apps-script, shopify, webhooks

I have this google apps script I wrote that I'm using as a web app as an endpoint for a Shopify webhook.

The issue I'm having is that Shopify has a 5 second limit to receive a success response otherwise the webhook will fire again to ensure you don't miss it.

The problem is my script takes too long to finish triggering a duplicate webhook which runs my code multiple times which I don't want.

Is there a way to respond quicker or clean up my script to finish quicker?

PLEASE NOTE: I need my script to be easily modified since exact values might change or be different in final version as I'm still developing this app. (additionally I need a way that if a value is missing it will leave that column blank, hence not mixing up value with column headers)

```
function doPost(e){
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 
  var l = data.line_items.length; 
 
  for (var i=0;i<l;i++){
  var prop = data.line_items[i].properties;


  if (prop.length>0){
  var pdf = prop.find(function(x) {if(x.name == "_pdf") return x});
  if (!pdf){pdf = "Prop not found";}else{pdf = pdf.value};
  
  var shape = prop.find(function(x) {if(x.name.toLowerCase() == "shape") return x});
  if (!shape){shape = "Prop not found";}else{shape = shape.value};
  
  var test = prop.find(function(x) {if(x.name == "test") return x});
  if (!test){test = "Prop not found";}else{test = test.value};

  }else{
  var pdf = "N/A"
  var shape = "N/A"
  var test = "N/A"
  };


  var count = "Item "+ (i+1) + " of " + l;
  var qty = data.line_items[i].quantity;
  var title = data.line_items[i].title;
  var id = data.id.toString();
  var email = data.email;
  var totalPrice = data.total_price;
  var discounts = data.total_discounts;
  var acceptAds = data.buyer_accepts_marketing;
  var orderStatus = data.order_status_url;
  var addr = data.shipping_address.address1;
  var city = data.shipping_address.city;
  var state = data.shipping_address.province;
  var zip = data.shipping_address.zip;
  var phone = data.shipping_address.phone;
  var firstName = data.shipping_address.first_name;
  var lastName = data.shipping_address.last_name;
  var orderNum = data.name;
  var d = new Date(data.created_at).toLocaleString();
  ss.appendRow([d,orderNum,email,count,title,shape,test,qty,totalPrice,discounts,pdf,firstName,lastName,addr,city,state,zip,phone,orderStatus]);
  
if (pdf != "N/A"){
if (pdf != "Prop not found"){
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdf);
  var blob = res.getBlob();
  var createFile = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx').createFile(blob.getAs('application/pdf'));
  var fileName = orderNum + " " + qty;
  createFile.setName(fileName);
}}
  };
}
```

Comment: i notice your using do post, is there a way you could run must of the code with a doGet and then have the doPost finish triggering the duplicate webhook when wanted? it would cut down on the time if you could at least store the variables and such before hand.

Comment: @Baby_Boy Shopify doesn't let you choose the method. I could perhaps store the data in a cell on the sheet and do the function through a trigger but it's a very clumsy way and is prone to problems if I'm having multiple webhooks coming in for separate events.

Comment: could you have a whole different script that will store and then send the info? or would that be even slower?  edit: you could even have a middleman script that would collect the info from separate events and send it as one thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would accomplish by adding scripts because this `doPost` function will wait for a response so it will take the same long. Can you identify what is slowing down this script? is it the `createFile` ?

Comment: You could try processing the data later and just work on getting the return sent back as  quickly as possible.

Comment: I believe its the storing of variables, if you could formulate the duplicate web hook in another script then have the one tied to shopify only receive it, then trigger it during the 5 second limit.

Comment: @Cooper that would work but I do you have any ideas how to do that with google apps script alone without any other servers

Comment: Well you only need to process the data when you look at it so you could do that manually or you could programmatically create a trigger to do that later and save the JSON as a string in PropertiesService.

Comment: @Baby_Boy I believe your not understanding the duplicate thing. Shopify keeps sending the same webhook of a single event until they receive a successful (200) response. I only want to get it once

Comment: if you could have the success response ready to send, you could send it faster and therefore receive less responses.

Comment: @Cooper I need it done programmatically. I think there is a limit on value length of a property service. additionally I may receive a few webhooks for different events how can I distinguish which property the triggered function should process?

Comment: Well creating a file is not very quick and probably never will be on Google

Comment: @Cooper if I can do that later through a button on my sheet which would batch create the files from a Url in a column, would I significantly cut down the script time and solve my issue? because that may be an option

Comment: These are all questions that you can answer yourself by writing a little code and doing some experimentation.  However, when I come to creating file I can say that it is something that takes a long time in apps script

Comment: @Cooper - Thanks for that tip. Besides from the file creation is the way I'm referring to each of the values look like they are time consuming? does the `find()` function take time?

Answer (score 0):

It's slower than using the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service), but I like using Sheets as a queue. (I use this with services that require responses within 3 seconds.) Not only is it easier to work with, but I've actually had issues with using Properties that are addressed with the [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) method:

> Appends a row to the spreadsheet. This operation is atomic; it prevents issues where a user asks for the last row, and then writes to that row, and an intervening mutation occurs between getting the last row and writing to it.

When you receive the POST data, simply add it to the queue and terminate. Apps Script will send a 200 success response, so Shopify shouldn't send duplicate requests.

Then have a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that runs a `processQueue()` function at the interval of your choice.

```
function doPost(e) {
  const queue = new Queue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(), "Unprocessed", "Processed");
  queue.append(e.postData.contents, skipRefresh = true);
}

function processQueue() {
  const queue = new Queue(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(), "Unprocessed", "Processed");
  while (queue.hasNext()) {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(queue.next());
      
      doSomethingWithShopifyData(data); // Process your data
      
      queue.moveToProcessed();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      queue.skip();
    }
  }
}

function doSomethingWithShopifyData(data) { /* your existing code, but with appropriate modifications */ }
```

Here's the class I use to abstract the spreadsheet into a queue. I have it setup to preserve all of the data moving it from an unprocessed to a processed sheet. You may prefer to simply delete the data once processed.

```
/**
 * A spreadsheet is used as a makeshift queue for processing requests asynchronously.
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId - The ID of the spreadsheet to be used for the queue.
 * @param {string} unprocessedSheetName - The name of the sheet to be used for storing unprocessed items.
 * @param {string} processedSheetName - The name of the sheet to be used for storing processed items.
 */
class Queue {
  constructor(spreadsheetId, unprocessedSheetName, processedSheetName) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.row = 1;
    this.spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
    this.unprocessedSheet = this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(unprocessedSheetName);
    this.processedSheet = this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(processedSheetName);
  }
  
  /**
   * Determines whether calling next() will return an item.
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  hasNext() {
    if (this.unprocessedValues == null) { this.refreshUnprocessedValues(); }
    return this.index < this.unprocessedValues.length;
  }
  
  /**
   * Get and save the unprocessed element values to the queue.
   * @returns {object[]}
   */
  refreshUnprocessedValues() {
    try {
      const range =this.unprocessedSheet.getRange(1, 1, this.unprocessedSheet.getLastRow());
      this.unprocessedValues = range.getValues();
    } catch (error) {
      this.unprocessedValues = [];
    }
    return this.unprocessedValues;
  }
  
  /**
   * Get the next element from the queue.
   * @returns {string}
   */
  next() {
    return this.unprocessedValues[this.index++][0];
  }
  
  /**
   * Skip the current queue element. Update row property to maintain synchronization
   * with the spreadsheet range.
   */
  skip() {
    this.row++;
  }
  
  /**
   * Add new data to the queue for processing.
   * @param {string} data - The data to add to the queue.
   * @param {boolean} [skipRefresh] - Default: false. If true, will skip refreshing the queue values.
   */
  append(data, skipRefresh) {
    this.unprocessedSheet.appendRow([data]);
    if (!skipRefresh) { this.refreshUnprocessedValues(); }
  }
  
  /**
   * Move a payload out of the unprocessed sheet and into the processed sheet. Uses the payload
   * at the top of the unprocessed range.
   */
  moveToProcessed() {
    const cell = this.unprocessedSheet.getRange(this.row, 1);
    
    // Move into processed sheet
    this.processedSheet.appendRow([cell.getValue()]);
    
    // Move out of unprocessed sheet
    cell.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```